# What is a phrase like "annus horribilis" but meaning a year of change?

Tags: phrase-request

What is a Latin phrase similar to "annus horribilis" meaning *a year of change*, as in a year where everything changes?

For example - a year in which I moved across the country, totally changed job etc I would refer to it in Latin as my "year of change".

Comment: Welcome!  If you have a specific type of change in mind, that'd be useful information to include here.  Another way to improve the accuracy of any answer you get here would be to [consult a dictionary](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/867/12) and choose the word for "change" that you think fits your context best.  Then we can put it into the right form.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**There was one year that became especially proverbial for change.**

In the year of the Seven Emperors. **anno Septem Imperatorum...**

> ...emperor #1 appointed his son joint-emperor. The senate already hated
>   the man and appointed an 83-year-old, who said he couldn't do it
>   without his son's help, so they were appointed the REAL two emperors:
>   but they died in a serious defeat. Two more tried. An unfortified town
>   wore the original Emperors down; starved their army; resisted a siege.
>   Emperor #7 was appointed in celebration. (Read the [Loeb text](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Historia_Augusta/Maximini_duo*.html) here: posted by Thayer)

This is all too much for Vikipedia; who have one short page on another hectic year:

The Year of the Five Emperors, **[Annus Quinque Imperatorum](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annus_quinque_imperatorum)** which had much less change of course, but still slightly proverbial.

More simply, **mutabilis,** means 'changeable,' (describing a *mind,* a *woman,* a *face,* and (variusque labor) work.) . But if I met *'annus mutabilis,'* I would think of normal change, new fashions, changing seasons, weather, the varying year. A stronger phrase would be : **Annus mutabilitatis,** a year of change. (ponounced mootabilita:tis).

If as a result of change everything is now upside down, back to front and inside out, say **Annus Inversus.**

Comment: Does _annus mutabilis_ have a better or different connotation than _annus mutationis?_ Or does the latter actually not make sense? Or how about _annus mutationum?_

Comment: *mutabilis* mean "changeable", so I think it is too much of a stretch to have *annus mutabilis* mean "a year in which many changes have occurred." *Mutabilis* was common in literature, an aspect of the "sublunar realm," and has a much different connotation than just "major life events occurred."